# React Native - Child Component won't finish rendering after Child Event called that updates Parent's state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my project, I'm looping through cards in my Child Component, and updating the Parent's state with ones where I activate an event of 'swiping right' on the card to favorite. The parent's state keeps track of all favorites by adding the favorited card to the array.

I'm passing down a function (`updatestate`)from the Parent Component, `App`, to the Child, `Main`, that allows the Child to call `.setState()` and append to the array in the Parent state.

But, when I activate the eventhandler `onSwipedRight` inside the Child Component, the parent's state gets updated as planned with the new Card, but nothing below the `<Card>` in `Main` gets rendered automatically for the next card, as it should. If I tap the screen, then the next card/picture renders only then.

Any ideas? Am I missing some binding or need to do some componentDidMount or anything so the code in child component, `Main`, renders even after I activate the event handler that updates the parent state?

**Basically,** **is there a tool in React to make sure something renders or at least waits for it to render? (post event handling which sets the parents state in my case)**

```
collection = imagedata;
//collection is the data (local JSON) i'm looping thru via .map in Main Component

const RootStack = StackNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: Main}
  }
);

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        favoritesList: []
      };
    }

  updateArr=(itemname, url)=>{this.setState({ favoritesList: [...this.state.favoritesList, {"item_name":itemname, "url":url}]})};

  render() {
      return <RootStack screenProps={{appstate: this.state,
                                    updatestate: this.updateArr}}
      />;
    }
  }

class Main extends React.Component {

  render() {
    var updatestate = this.props.screenProps.updatestate;

    const contents = collection.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <Card key={index}
                  onSwipedRight={() => {updatestate(item.item_name,item.url)}}
            >
              <View> //THIS and anything after <Card> doesn't render for the next card automatically if I do 'onSwipedRight'
                <Image
                    source={{uri: item.url}} />
               </View>
            </Card>
        )
      },this);

      return (
      <View>
            <CardStack>

              {contents}

            </CardStack>
      </View>
        );
    }
}
```

(abbreviated) Project structure:

```
App
 |__ Rootstack
       |
       |__Main
```

**UPDATE (more info):**
Just to test the event handler, I added in a function that doesn't set the state of the parent, and had `<Card>` call that on the event handler -- it works perfectly and the child component `<Card>` renders perfectly. It seems that it's the `updatestate` function passed down from the parent to the child that acts to call `.setState()` upstream that for some reason is causing the Child to not render/not finish rendering after the event handler.

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {

    var updatestate = this.props.screenProps.updatestate;

    var newfunc = (a, b) => {console.log('a:', a, 'b:', b)};

      const contents = collection.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <Card key={index}
                  newfunc(item.item_name,item.item_name);}}
                  // onSwipedRight={() => {updatestate(item.item_name,item.url); }}
                  >
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set the state of a component based on the previous state, you should use

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => {})
```

Which should, in your case look like

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => {
  return {
    favoritesList: [
      ...prevState.favoritesList,
      {"item_name":itemname, "url":url}
    ]
  };
})
```

For more on [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: thanks! but what about the 2nd answer here on 'correct way of pushing into state array'? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435334/correct-way-to-push-into-state-array -- also, how would your solution eliminate the non-rendering-after-event-handling issue?

Comment: with destructuring, the state is still immutable it's not a dirty way if you want a more efficient way, personally I prefer working with {} than [].

Comment: as of the non-rendering-after-event-handling issue, as I didn't test your code  I don't see why it's not updating. you could try destructuring `this.state` when passing it as a prop to `RootStack` to be sure it doesn't get mutated

Comment: what do you mean when you say destructuring? Could you give an example of what destructuring is?

Comment: also, thanks for the help and advice btw - but not sure it answers my question (added a section in bold to my original question up top that summarizes the real nature of my question)

Comment: maybe it's not the right term but I mean by destructuring assignments like `const a = { ...b }` as it will create a new object `a` by destructuring `b`

Comment: there is [forceUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) to force a React component to update, but normally you shouldn't use it if your design is following to react principles