# Pushing To React State Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

How can I write this better , I want to do it with setState instead of this.state.floors.push as I know that is bad practice but I couldnt figure it out. Im using react native.

```
FloorAPI.getFloorsByBuildingID(this.state.buildingID).then((response) => response.d.data.map((value) => {
  console.log(value.floorName)
  this.state.floors.push({value: value.floorName})
}))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to push into state array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435334/correct-way-to-push-into-state-array)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
// Create a new array based on current state:
let floors = [...this.state.floors];

// Add item to it
floors.push({ value: floorName });

// Set state
this.setState({ floors });
```

Comment: Simple and works great, thank you. Although whats with the three periods, why is that required?

Comment: It was a little weird for me to wrap my head around but the `...` is part of a concept called "destructuring": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: best meaningful coding.

Answer (score 5):

In hooks form u may use

```
setState((prevVals) => [...prevVals,newVals])
```

Answer (score 3):

For now, the best possible and simplest way is

```
  this.setState(previousState => ({
      floors: [...previousState.floors, {"value": value.floorName}]
  }));
```

Comment: i got error

TypeError : Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

Comment: @RayCoder The reason why you're getting `TypeError : Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance` because the data which you are using to destruct is not an array and the reason it not iterable and the reason why you got the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
FloorAPI.getFloorsByBuildingID(this.state.buildingID).then((response) => { 
  // get current floors
  const { floors } = this.state;

  // get new floors after api request
  const newfloors = response.d.data.map((value) => ({value: value.floorName}))

  // set the new state by combining both arrays
  this.setState({ floors: [...floors, ...newfloors] });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
this.setState({floors: [{value: value.floorName}]});
```

in order to use set state.

Comment: This works in a way but its only putting one item in the array, and I need all of the floors to be in this array since its going to be populating a dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new variable and push to the variable then set the state after the map is complete

```
var tempArray = []

FloorAPI.getFloorsByBuildingID(this.state.buildingID).then((response) => response.d.data.map((value) => {
  tempArray.push({value: value.floorName})
}))

this.setState({floors: tempArray})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const { floors } = this.state;

// Add item to it
floors.push({ value: 5 });

// Set state
this.setState({ floors });
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot but what worked for me was .concat() function

```
import react,{useState} from 'react'

const [files,setFiles] = useState([]);

function addUp(acceptedFiles){
 // the code below adds up to the state, using the args
 setFiles((prev) => {
   return prev.concat(acceptedFiles);
 }); 
}

return <div> </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always use the previous state.

```
setState((prevState)=>({
   floors: prevState.floors.push({...})
});
```

Thats a nice way to avoid directly changing the state. Another way would be to do the following:

```
var newState=[...this.state.floors];
newState.push({...});

setState(()=>({
  floors: newState
)}
```

Comment: This is kind of a mishmash of two solutions. In your first solution, you should not modify `prevState.floors`, which is what `push` does, and in your second solution you do not need to pass a callback to `setState` if you're producing an object that doesn't use the callback's `state` argument.

Comment: Thanks! Did not now that I was not allowed to modify the prevState. Now when you pointed it out I can see the reason for it.