# Selecting Multiple options in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some data in arrays. I am getting it by using map, as you see in the below example. Also, i pass that into the button. Now, if, i select a button, it will get selected. But, if i select the next button, the previous button will get unselected and the current button will get selected. I don't want it to happen. I want to select multi buttons, if it all get clicked.

Thanks in advance.

**Below is the Solution**

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';


const BUTTONS = [
    {id:0, title:'button1'},
    {id:1, title:'button2'},
    {id:2, title:'button3'}
]
class Map extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            values: []
        }
    }
    handleButton = button => {
        let tmp = this.state.values;
        if (this.state.values.includes(button)) {
            this.setState({
                values: this.state.values.filter(el => el !== button)
            })
        } else {
            tmp.push(button);
            this.setState({
                values: tmp
            })
        }
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                {BUTTONS.map(bt=>(
                <button 
                    key={bt.id} 
                    onClick={()=>this.handleButton(bt.id)} 
                    className={this.state.values.includes(bt.id) ? "buttonPressed" : "button"}>
                    {bt.title}
                </button>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
} 

export default Map;
```

Comment: I may do something like:
`this.state = { clickedButtons: {}}`
Then on the buttons `className={this.state.clickedButtons[bt.id] ? "buttonPressed" : "button"}>`
Then the `handleButton` would look something like: `this.setState({clickedButtons:{
 [button]: true
}});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Selecting multiple `buttons`**

   you'd better use the `state` as an `array`.

```
this.state = {
  values: []
}
```

and you can `push` items.

```
let tmp = this.state.values;
tmp.push(button);
this.setState({
  values: tmp
});
```

in `render()` you have to check `state.values` has `bt.id`

```
className={this.state.values.includes(bt.id) ? "buttonPressed" : "button"
```

2. **Toggling multiple `buttons`**

   you can check in `handleButton()` whether that selected button is already selected

```
handleButton = button => {
  if (this.state.values.includes(button)) {
    this.setState({
      values: this.state.values.filter(el => el !== button)
    })
  }
```

```js
const BUTTONS = [
    { id: 0, title: 'button1' },
    { id: 1, title: 'button2' },
    { id: 2, title: 'button3' }
]
class Map extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            values: []
        }
    }

    handleButton = button => {
        let tmp = this.state.values;
        if (this.state.values.includes(button)) {
            this.setState({
                values: this.state.values.filter(el => el !== button)
            })
        } else {
            tmp.push(button);
            this.setState({
                values: tmp
            })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {BUTTONS.map(bt => (
                    <button
                        key={bt.id}
                        onClick={() => this.handleButton(bt.id)}
                        className={this.state.values.includes(bt.id) ? "buttonPressed" : "button"}>
                        {bt.title}
                    </button>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: Now, i am getting an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined"

Comment: @JeyanthKanagaraj do you use `let tmp`?

Comment: Yeah, now that error got cleared. But, when i click the button, it's doing noting. Not, even changing the class name. I updated the code above

Comment: @JeyanthKanagaraj `className={this.state.values.includes(bt.id) ? "buttonPressed" : "button"}>`

Comment: Oh, my bad. Thank You @zynkn

Answer (score 1):

The reason your button is getting deselected is because you're overwriting `this.state.value` every time you click a button.

If you want multiple selections, you'll need to hold all of the selected items in the state, as an array, and then when rendering, check if the button id is included in that array.

Something like:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';


const BUTTONS = [
    {id:0, title:'button1'},
    {id:1, title:'button2'},
    {id:2, title:'button3'}
]
class Map extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedValues: []
        }
    }

    handleButton = buttonId => {
        let newSelectedValues = this.state.selectedValues;
        newSelectedValues.push(buttonId);
        this.setState({
            selectedValues: newSelectedValues
        })
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                {BUTTONS.map(bt => (
                    <button 
                        key={bt.id} 
                        onClick={()=>this.handleButton(bt.id)} 
                        className={this.state.selectedValues.includes(bt.id) ? "buttonPressed" : "button"}>
                            {bt.title}
                    </button>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
} 

export default Map;
```

Comment: Now, i am getting an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined"

Comment: The answer has gone through a couple of edits and would have resulted in that. It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

if you need multiple selections you need an array:

```
this.state = {
   values:[]
}
```

and push it on each clicks 
[Correct way to push into state array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435334/correct-way-to-push-into-state-array)