# How to push new value into array of object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, ecmascript-2016

I think it might be silly question to ask but trust I am new to React . I am trying to push new key and value to array of object but I am not able to do it . Could someone please help me how to achieve my goal. Thanks

**Code**

```
this.state= {
cartItems=[
{name:'item1',price:'$23'},
{name:'item2',price:'$26'},
{name:'item3',price:'$24'},
]
```

I want to add new value like `quantity:0` in the end of array of object. Please help me

Comment: Is it state not updating in DOM or in the object?

Comment: What have you done so far to make this work? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I literally googled your thread header : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435334/correct-way-to-push-into-state-array

Comment: Do you mean to add `quantity: 0` for *each* object or as a *separate object* at the end of the array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to push into state array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435334/correct-way-to-push-into-state-array)

Comment: @leonardfactory Yes, I want to add `quantity:0` it the end of each object

Comment: @emrhzc No , actually my question is different

Comment: @leonardfactory could you please help me on this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update state adding a property to each object, you should just use `setState` in combination with `map`. `Array.prototype.map` allows you to transform each object, like this:

```
this.setState(state => {
  cartItems: state.cartItems.map(cartItem => ({ 
    ...cartItem, // Keep all old properties
    quantity: 0 // Add quantity
  })
})
```

You should do this only if you're calling `setState` **after the initializer**. If you need to modifiy the data right when assigning to `this.state`, just map the array directly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this

```
const newState = this.state.cartItems.map(item => {
  item.quantity = 0;

  return item;
});

this.setState({cartItems: newState});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.state= {
  cartItems:[
    {name:'item1',price:'$23'},
    {name:'item2',price:'$26'},
    {name:'item3',price:'$24'},
  ]
}
updateCartItems=()=>{ 
   var cartItems = this.state.cartItems.map((item)=>{
      return {...item,quantity:0}
   })
   this.setState({cartItems})
}
```

Comment: did you call updateCartItems function? like ex: componentDidMount() { this.updateCartItems() }

Comment: Yes, I called this method in componentdidmount

Comment: Just to highlight it, you used `filter` instead of map and wrote `quality` instead of `quantity`