# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. What should I fix?

Tags: json, reactjs, api

I got the error when I tried to get some datas from api.

Then I searched how to solve this error but I couldn't solve. I want to solove this error.
I don't know Why do I get this error.
What should I fix my code ??
Please tell me any ideas.
thank you for reading !

this is my error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

and message image.
[image]

this is my code.

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';

class Exchange extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoaded: false,
      items: [],
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        items: json.items,
      })
    })
    }

    render(){
      var { items,isLoaded } = this.state;

      if(!isLoaded){
        return <div>...Loading</div>;
      }else{
        return (
          <div>
            <ul>
              {items.map(item =>(
                <li key={item.rates}>{item.CAD}</li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
}

 export default Exchange;
```

and this is using api.
[image]

Comment: `items` is not an array. `map is applicable on array. You need to convert the data into array of objects. Check this: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: in this case you can check your state with [React Dev Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi). likely @sidverma said, `items` is not array.

Comment: can you console `json.items`? i think this part made problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way you access the data from api is wrong it should be

```
this.setState({
    isLoaded: true,
    items: json.rates //json.rates not json.items
});
```

and when rendering it, map expecting a array so you have do something like this

```
<ul>
    {Object.keys(items).map(key => (
        <li key={key}>{key} - {items[key]}</li>
     ))}
</ul>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jnfnnm)

Comment: fantastic ! My app worked well  !. thank you ! I could learn how I shoud do get json data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no attribute `items` in the json response. That's why `items` is undefined after following statement : `items: json.items`.

Also, `map()` is only applicable to array. Response from the API you are calling is not Array.

You can modify code something like

```js
this.setState({
    isLoaded: true,
    items: json,
})
```

And

```
<ul>              
    <li>{items.rates.CAD}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: good ! I could get json data and write on browser ! thank you

Answer (score 0):

To change the state of the array `this.setState({ items: [...this.state.items, itemsArr] })`
If the your response of API is array you can follow the above way.

But in your API response it seems like object, to push object into an array [gothrough the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435334/correct-way-to-push-into-state-array)

Comment: Thank you for replying ! I actually miss converting  object to array... I could learn well. thank you for helping!