# Can you use array.push in useEffect? React Hooks

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to figure out a way to add objects into my array. Here's the code.

```
export default function DashboardTable(props) {
    const { transactionData } = props;
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [transactionDataArray, setTransactionDataArray] = useState([])

 
  useEffect(() => {
    setTransactionDataArray(transactionDataArray.push(transactionData))
  }, [transactionData])

    console.log(transactionDataArray);
```

transactionData returns objects (the amount of objects is variable depending on the back end transactions.) I want to add the objects to the array `transactionDataArray` but I keep getting the error `transactionDataArray is not a function`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: try like this setTransactionDataArray([...transactionDataArray, transactionData])

Comment: Please read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) about what `Array.prototype.push` actually does. It does not return the updated array, it returns the length of the new array. In addition, `push` mutates the original array which is against the rules of React state.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to push into state array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435334/correct-way-to-push-into-state-array)

Comment: @RajaJaganathan. Technically it works? but it nests the arrays deeper into each other [like this](https://imgur.com/a/TlG7YA8)

Comment: @BrianThompson hmmmm. i see. will look into that

Comment: Can you share your transactionDataArray shapes? Also, your transactionDataArray is a complex object probably you could try to use useReducer than useState.

Comment: @RajaJaganathan Here [you go](https://imgur.com/a/27npChu) As you can see, I'm getting multiple objects. I want to store those objects and turn it into an array so I can use the map method,

Comment: @Pacholoamit You did not follow the Raja's instructions.. Your image shows you spreading into an object, it must be an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use push in useEffect but not on the state. React state can not be changed directly. As being a state you can not directly push or edit data of the state `transactionDataArray`. But with the help of `setTransactionDataArray` function you can change/set the state value. so for you to add new value to it's older state you have to destructure the old state and add the new value like below

```
setTransactionDataArray([...transactionDataArray, transactionData])
```

or you can do it like below by creating new variable assigning state's value and than push the new value to the variable and last set the state

```
const data = transactionDataArray;
data.push(transactionData);
setTransactionDataArray(data);
```

for more about react state [read here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Comment: You've solved it. Thanks. I would've never thought to do it this way.

Comment: The second solution still mutates state, it just avoids the return value of length issue. You **should never** mutate state. You need to create a new array but following the first example, or spreading the previous values `[...transactionDataArray]`.

Comment: Ahhh yes, I tried the 2nd solution of this post but it was always delayed by 1. I tried using the spread operator `[...transactionDataArray, transactionData]` and it worked perfectly. I'd for Raja to post his answer so I make it the official answer.

Answer (score 0):

To add data to your local state you don't have to use push but only "setTransactionDataArray" because that's the function that will add data to state.

So in your useEffect

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setTransactionDataArray(transactionData)
  }, [transactionData])
```

Or if you want to have an array with data then later add that array to state than you should declare an array and add data to it. Then when the job is done you can add that array in state.

Comment: Yeah this only gets the latest object. So you'd be only getting the latest transaction from `transactionData`. I'm trying to get all of the data and add it into the array