# React - how to use map to pass an array of options on input of type unform select

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, select, input, unform

I have a select input where I want to pass an options array object using map but when rendering my page only one option even when the array I'm using in the map has several items it insists on presenting only one

below all the code:

```
export default function PesquisarAulas() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.profile);
  const [docente, setDocente] = useState([]);
  const [docenteDisciplinas, setDocenteDisciplinas] = useState([]);
  const [disciplinas, setDisciplinas] = useState([]);
  const updateDisciplinas = [...disciplinas];

  

  async function carregarDocente() {
    const response = await api.get(`docente/findByUser/${user.id}`);

    return response.data;
  }

  async function carregarDisciplinasDocente() {
    const response = await api.get(`docente/${docente.id}/disciplinas`);

    return response.data;
  }

  async function carregarDisciplina(disc) {
    const response = await api.get(`disciplinas/${disc.id_disciplina}`);

    return response.data;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    carregarDocente().then((value) => {
      setDocente(value);
    });
  }, [user]);

  useEffect(() => {
    carregarDisciplinasDocente().then((value) => {
      setDocenteDisciplinas(value);
    });
  }, [docente]);

  useEffect(() => {
    docenteDisciplinas.map((docDisc) =>
      carregarDisciplina(docDisc).then((value) => {
        updateDisciplinas.push(value);
        setDisciplinas(updateDisciplinas);
      })
    );
  }, [docenteDisciplinas]);

  console.log(disciplinas);
 

  function handleSubmit() {}

  return (
    <Container>
      <div className="title">Pesquisar aulas</div>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="input-box">
          <span>Ano Letivo:</span>
          <Input
            name="anoLetivo1"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Introduza o ano letivo"
          />
        </div>

        <div className="input-box">
          <span>Disciplinas:</span>
          <Select
            name="tech"
            options={disciplinas.map((disciplina) => ({
              id: disciplina.id,
              title: disciplina.nome,
            }))}
            placeholder="Nenhum selecionado"
          />
        </div>

        <div className="input-box">
          <span>Aulas de:</span>
          <Input name="dataInicio1" type="datetime-local" id="pickup_time" />
          <span style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }}>ate:</span>
          <Input name="dataFinal1" type="datetime-local" id="pickup_time" />
        </div>

        <div className="input-box">
          <span>Curso:</span>
          <Input name="curso1" type="text" placeholder="Introduza o curso" />
        </div>

        <div className="input-box">
          <span>Unidade Curricular:</span>
          <Input
            name="unidadeCurricular1"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Introduza a unidade curricular"
          />
        </div>

        <hr />

        <button type="submit">Pesquisar</button>
      </Form>
     
    </Container>
  );
}
```

the focus of the problem is on these two code snippets here:

```
const [disciplinas, setDisciplinas] = useState([]);
  const updateDisciplinas = [...disciplinas];


useEffect(() => {
    docenteDisciplinas.map((docDisc) =>
      carregarDisciplina(docDisc).then((value) => {
        updateDisciplinas.push(value);
        setDisciplinas(updateDisciplinas);
      })
    );
  }, [docenteDisciplinas]);


  <Select
            name="tech"
            options={disciplinas.map((disciplina) => ({
              id: disciplina.id,
              title: disciplina.nome,
            }))}
            placeholder="Nenhum selecionado"
          />
```

I think the problem is that when the select is rendered only one item is inserted in the disciplines array,
I think maybe if there was a way to make Select wait until all the items in the disciplines array are ready so it can render, the problem would be solved.

Comment: Using push on a state in useEffect is a bit tricky. Have a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65008812/can-you-use-array-push-in-useeffect-react-hooks

Comment: you're right i'm stuck on this for hours, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try using the select like this:

```
<select placeholder="Nenhum selecionado" >
    {{disciplinas.map((disciplina) => {
        <option value={disciplina.nome}>
            {disciplina.nome}
        </option>
    })}}
</select>
```