# How can I store previous values instead of storing the value in array of objects in react state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, next.js

I am storing the prev values in an array of objects, for example `[{ActFollow: 'BlN'},{ActSendGift: 'BlY'},{ActSubscribe: 'BlY'}]` I want to store the key and values in an object like this {ActFollow: 'BlN',ActSendGift: 'BlY', ActSubscribe: 'BlY'}

```
  const [activityTypes, setActivityTypes] = useState<any>([]); // state
 .then((response: any) => {
            setActivityTypes((oldArray: any) => [
              ...oldArray,
              {[item.channelSettingTypeId]: response.settingValue},
            ]);
          });
```

Comment: You want to store each object from array of objects in single object ?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: [kindly check this link, I think it is helpful for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435334/correct-way-to-push-into-state-array)

Comment: @Jerin Just added answer. Please check that. Its pretty simple

Answer (score 1):

You can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array of objects into an object.

You can do it by [spreading (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the current object into the resultant object, as shown below:

```js
const 
  arrOfObjs = [{ ActFollow: "BlN" }, { ActSendGift: "BlY" }, { ActSubscribe: "BlY" }],
  obj = arrOfObjs.reduce((res, o) => ({ ...res, ...o }), {});

console.log(obj);
```

You can also do it using [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), as shown below:

```js
const 
  arrOfObjs = [{ ActFollow: "BlN" }, { ActSendGift: "BlY" }, { ActSubscribe: "BlY" }],
  obj = arrOfObjs.reduce((res, o) => Object.assign(res, o), {});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this, **if the nesting is only one level deep**

```js
const data = [{ActFollow: 'BlN',ActSendGift: 'BlY', ActSubscribe: 'BlY'}]

console.log([{...data[0],"hey" : "world"}])
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const items = [{ActFollow: 'BlN'},{ActSendGift: 'BlY'},{ActSubscribe: 'BlY'}]

let object = {}
items.forEach(item=>{
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
    object = {
      ...object,
      [key]: value
    }
  }
})
console.log(object)
```

You can use this simple idea in React also. Just hold on the default empty object in state and update the object.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spread Operator

```js
const items = [{ActFollow: 'BlN', Anurag: 26},{ActSendGift: 'BlY'},{ActSubscribe: 'BlY'}]
    let obj ={}
    items.forEach((item) => {
      obj = {
        ...obj,
        ...item
        }
      })
    console.log(obj)
```