# Count array item every time condition is met with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, react-hooks, count

Im trying to set a counter everytime this condition is met in every array.push :

```
    interface FilterProps {
            filterQuery: any
            setFilterQuery: (e: any) => any
            resetFilter: (e: any) => any
            handleCategory: (e: any) => any
            categoryList: any
            getCategoryValue: any
            handleOnClick: (e: any) => any
            paginateOnClick: (e: any) => any
            paginateIcon: any
            handleToggle: (e: any) => any
            checkState: any
            expandFilter: boolean
            printEvent: PrintEvent
        }
        
        export const EventFilter: React.FC<FilterProps> = ({
            filterQuery,
            setFilterQuery,
            resetFilter,
            handleCategory,
            categoryList,
            getCategoryValue,
            handleOnClick,
            paginateOnClick,
            paginateIcon,
            handleToggle,
            checkState,
            expandFilter,
        }, printEvent: PrintEvent) => {
        
        
             const [countUnlabeled, setCountUnlabeled] = React.useState(0)
            
                const classes = useStyles()
            
                const { box, ui } = useStores()
            
                const { labels } = printEvent
            
                let unlabeledEvents: any[] = []
            
                function getUnlabeled() {
                    box.descEvents.forEach((printEvent: PrintEvent) => {
            
            
         
            
                        const isStopEvent =
                            (printEvent && printEvent.name === 'control_fault') ||
                            (printEvent.name === 'running' && printEvent.value === false) ||
                            (printEvent.name === 'safety_chain' && printEvent.value === false) ||
                            (printEvent.name === 'torch_collision' && printEvent.value === true) ||
                            (printEvent.name === 'motion_sup' && printEvent.value === true) ||
                            (printEvent.name === 'e_stop' && printEvent.value === true)
            
                        const unlabeled = printEvent.labels === null && isStopEvent
            
            
                        if (unlabeled) {
                            unlabeledEvents.push(unlabeled)
                            ui.setUnlabeledCount(unlabeledEvents.length)
                        }
            
                    })
                }
    
    
        useEffect(() => {
            if (box.descEvents && printEvent) {
                getUnlabeled()
                console.log('useEffect just ran', ui.unlabeledCount, unlabeledEvents.length)
            }
        }, [unlabeledEvents, ui.unlabeledCount, printEvent.name])
    
        return (
            <Accordion
                className={classes.eventAccordion}
                TransitionProps={{ unmountOnExit: true }}
                defaultExpanded={expandFilter}
            >
                <AccordionSummary>
                    <div className={classes.filterHeader}>
                        <div className={classes.filterText}>
                            <FilterListIcon />
                            <p>Filter by:</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className={classes.unfiltered}>
                            Unlabeled events: &nbsp;
                            <Chip
                                size="small"
                                label={ui.unlabeledCount}
                                className={classes.chipMissing}
                            />
    
                        </div>
    
                    </div>
                </AccordionSummary>
    </Accordion>

export default EventFilter
```

normally it should run the functuion check everytime the event is pushed or there are changes in the array, but its not counting sychronously.
i tried adding a count to the unlabeled conditional but doesnt work and dont want to overcomplicate things here.

What is the problem here?

[counter example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMJXN.png)

Comment: Effects are run after render. Setting state causes renders. You have a setState call (or what looks like one) inside a loop. Setting state is async and batched. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: basically to increment the counter (unlabeled events) everytime the unlabeled condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

In React, stuff you write inside the functional component body is run on every render. That means

```
let unlabeledEvents: any[] = [];
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(unlabeledEvents);
}, [unlabeledEvents]);
```

creates a fresh array every time the component is rendered, leaving the object reference (or length, or any other property) unchanged. If you want to react changes to an object, you need a way to store the old reference somewhere and then update it in a way that creates a new reference. This is exactly what the [`useState`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState) hook is for. Just make sure a new array is created every time in order to update that reference:

```
const [unlabeledEvents, setUnlabeledEvents] = useState<any[]>([]);

function getUnlabeled() {
     // find unlabeled item
     if (unlabeled) {
          setUnlabeledEvents([...unlabeledEvents, unlabeled]);
     }
}
```

This way your `useEffect` runs every time `getUnlabeled` adds a new entry to the `unlabeledEvents` array. You can also ditch `countUnlabeled`, since `unlabeledEvents` will always be up to date, you can use its length directly instead.

However, are you sure your `useStores` hooks works as expected? Since we don't know anything about it, it could suffer from the same problem as described above. And if it does, I'd recommend using [`useMemo`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useMemo) instead, to recalculate the array every time `box` is changed (since you're iterating the entire array anyways):

```
const { box } = useStores();

const unlabeledEvents = useMemo(
    box.descEvents.filter((e) => true /* your unlabeled condition here */),
    [box]
)
```

Also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37435334/13257467) for some more details on updating stateful arrays in a component.