# Adding new object to useState array

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, asyncstorage

So I am trying to add to a useState array of objects however it is getting overwritten everytime I try to add something new to it.

I define my state

```
const [habits, setHabits] = useState([]);
```

make multiple calls to return a data object

```
asyncStorageKeys.forEach(key => {
 getDataObject(key, habits, setHabits);
});
```

getDataObject looks like this

```
export const getDataObject = async (key, data, setData) => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    return jsonValue != null ? setData([...data, JSON.parse(jsonValue)]) : null;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error returning data object in AsyncStorage, error: ' + e);
  }
};
```

But when I console.log using

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(habits);
}, [habits]);
```

It shows that the array is just being overwritten everytime

```
 LOG  []
 LOG  [{"daysPerWeek": 3, "name": "another one"}]
 LOG  [{"daysPerWeek": 7, "name": "test"}]
 LOG  [{"daysPerWeek": 6, "name": "testing"}]
 LOG  [{"daysPerWeek": 6, "name": "tests"}]
```

I have looked on react.dev (https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state) for the recommended way to do this however it is not working for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to push into state array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435334/correct-way-to-push-into-state-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you call `setData([...data, JSON.parse(jsonValue)])` you add the current item to the original state and then set it as the state, and the last addition would overwrite all the others. For example, if you have a state of `[1, 2, 3]`, and you want to add the values - 4, 5, 6, the end state would be `[1, 2, 3, 6]`. See [Updating state based on the previous state](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state).

To prevent that you can you can use an updater function, that takes the last updated state on each iteration:

```
 setData(prev => [...prev, JSON.parse(jsonValue)])
```

However, it's better make all async calls at once using `Array.map()`, wait for all of them to finish with `Promise.all()`, and then update the state while filtering `null` values:

```
export const getDataObjects = async() => {
  try {
    const values = await Promise.all( // wait for all promises to resolve
      // create an array of promises
      asyncStorageKeys.map(key => 
        AsyncStorage.getItem(key).then(v => JSON.parse(v))
      )
    );
    
    // add all non null values to previous state
    setData(prev => [...prev, ...values.filter(v => v !== null)])
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error returning data object in AsyncStorage, error: ' + e);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this, I added in `values = values.map(value => JSON.parse(value));` as the data being set was still in json format. There is only one remaining issue now, the console.log shows an empty array at the start `[[], [{"daysPerWeek": 3, "name": "another one"}, {"daysPerWeek": 7, "name": "test"}, {"daysPerWeek": 6, "name": "testing"}, {"daysPerWeek": 6, "name": "tests"}]]`. This does not appear if I console.log the json data.

Comment: Fixed. I've added a JSON parsing to the map. I've also added the missing `values` spread `setData(prev => [...prev, ...values.filter(v => v !== null)]).`

Comment: awesome thanks that's fixed the remaining issues

Answer (score 1):

You might be introducing a race condition with your forEach function, since getDataObject is async. Try awaiting each call before continuing.

```js
let combined = [];
for (key of asyncStorageKeys) {
    const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
  if (!jsonValue) continue;
  combined = [...combined, JSON.parse(jsonValue)];
}
setHabits(combined);
```